# WSO2 - How to add Database Connector for Firebird

Tags: wso2, firebird, jaybird

I'm trying to add a Message Store using a Firebird SQL Database on WSO2 and it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

Of course WSO2 cannot find the jar/driver/class for the Firebird connection.

The question is: How to configure properly a Message Store using Firebird Sql Database on WSO2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue .I have solved by putting jar  in following location

```
<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/lib
```

You can  download jar from following link:

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/